# How do I create a Multidimensional Array which the dimension is determined by the length of the strings to create the array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I want to create a rectangular multidimensional array from a giving string gotten by input element in HTML. The dimensional of the rectangular will be determined by length of the string.

For example

```
ifmanwasmeanttostayonthegroundgodwouldhavegivenusroots
```

The plain text should be organized in to a rectangle. The size of the rectangle `(​r x c​)` should be decided by the length of the message, such that  ​`c >= r`​ and `​c - r <= 1`​,
where ​**c​** is the number of columns and ​r​ is the number of rows.
Our normalized text is 54 characters long, dictating a rectangle with ​c = 8​ and ​r = 7​:

`"ifmanwas"
"meanttos"
"tayonthe"
"groundgo"
"dwouldha"
"vegivenu"
"sroots`

Kindly check https://codepen.io/djtush/pen/ewvNEG to see what I have done.

```
const  myFunction = ()  =>
{
  let message = document.getElementById("message").value;
 if (message.length < 50) {
   alert ("Your Message can not be less than 50 Characters");
 }
  else {
  let removedSpace = message.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, '').toLowerCase();
  document.getElementById("noSpace").innerHTML = removedSpace;
  let squared = Math.sqrt(removedSpace.length);
  let column = Math.ceil(squared);
  let row = Math.floor(squared);
   document.getElementById("no-Space").innerHTML = row;
 }
}
```

I expect to have a block of array

Comment: There is more than one solution to your problem. What about a rectangle with r = 1 and c = 54?

Comment: This condition has to be satisfied  ``The size of the rectangle (​r x c​) should be decided by the length of the message, such that ​c >= r​ and ​c - r <= 1​, where ​c​ is the number of columns and ​r​ is the number of rows. ``

Comment: So what's wrong with your solution? `Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(length))` works just fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the regex do the job:

```js
s = 'ifmanwasmeanttostayonthegroundgodwouldhavegivenusroots'
n = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(s.length))
r = s.match(new RegExp(`.{1,${n}}`, 'g'))
console.log(r)
```

Comment: Kindly send a link where I can learn extensively about RegExp. I have a little knowledge of regular expression.

Comment: @Tush: the MDN page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Regular_expression is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You could start from the `cols = length of string` and then use while loop to increase the number of rows until `cols - rows > 1`. Then you can use number of cols to split the string.

```js
function rect(string) {
  let len = string.length;
  let cols = len, rows = 1;
  let res = []

  while (cols - rows > 1) {
    rows += 1;
    cols = Math.ceil(len / rows);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    res.push(string.slice(i * cols, i * cols + cols))
  }

  return res;
}

console.log(rect('ifmanwasmeanttostayonthegroundgodwouldhavegivenusroots'))
console.log(rect('randomteststring'))
```